# React native firebase functions. - OnCall stop to answer after an hour

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I got a react native application and I use react-native-firebase SDK to authenticate users.
I just add firebase functions, which I use like this

```
    try {
        const response = await FBfunction.app().functions('europe-west1').httpsCallable('getUser')();
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
```

The version of the sdk is 14.5.1.

My problem is the response is good after log in during an hour. After that, I got a error message : An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.
If I log out and log in, it will work again for an hour.
When it's not working, I check `alert(JSON.stringify(firebase.auth().currentUser));`
And it answer the correct information about the user.
I used onCall to get the context object and be sure in my function user is authenticated.

Does anyone ever met this problem ? Someone know how enable onCall more than an hour ?

EDIT :

Here the function call for my test :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
const androidGoogleMapsApiKey = functions.config().android.googlemaps.key;
const iosGoogleMapsApiKey = functions.config().ios.googlemaps.key;

// Create and deploy your first functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
exports.getUser = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        return context.auth.uid + '//' + context.auth.token.email;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Error', error);
    }
});
```

EDIT 2:
It's resolved. I didn't activate the google map API "Cloud functions". Apparently it have this weird behavior to work for an hour and stop after that.

Comment: Please provide the source code for your `getUser` function. It is currently unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: My getUser code is just an HelloWorld where I return information about the context. I have the same problem on all my others functions, log in, work for an hour, and stop to work. Thanks for your response